# Does the Perception that Stress Affects Health Matter? The Association with Health and Mortality

Tags: perception, well-being, stress, health-psychology, causal-inference

I recently came across the following paper:

[Keller, A., Litzelman, K., Wisk, L. E., Maddox, T., Cheng, E. R., Creswell, P. D., & Witt, W. P. (2012). Does the perception that stress affects health matter? The association with health and mortality. Health Psychology, 31(5), 677.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/pmc3374921/)

> This study tracked about thirty thousand adults in the US for 8 years
>   and they started by asking people "How much stress have you
>   experienced in the last year?" They also asked, "Do you believe that
>   stress is harmful to your health?" And then they used public death
>   records to figure out who died. They found that people who experienced
>   "a lot of" stress over the past year had a 43% increased risk of
>   dying, but that was only true for the people who also believed that
>   stress is harmful to their health. People who experienced a lot of
>   stress but did not view stress as harmful were no more likely to die.
>   In fact, they had the lowest risk of dying of anyone in the study,
>   including people who had relatively little stress. The researchers
>   estimated that over the eight years they were tracking deaths, 182,00
>   Americans died prematurely, not from stress, but from the belief that
>   stress is bad for them, which is over 20,000 deaths a year. If that
>   estimate is correct, that would make believing stress is bad for you,
>   the 15th largest cause of death in the United States last year, ...

[From: [Psychologist Kelly McGonigal's TED Talk: How to make stress your friend, Sep, 2013]](https://youtu.be/RcGyVTAoXEU)

Now, my questions is: "Is this study confounded?"
I think the way they have measured "How much stress have you experienced in the last year?" highly depends on the reference point defined individually for the subject. I may see an event as very stressful, and someone else may see the same event as not stressful at all. [For more information about refernce point, please look at: [Kahneman, D., & Tversky, A. (1979). Prospect theory: An analysis of decision under risk. Econometrica: Journal of the econometric society, 263-291.]](http://citec.repec.org/d/ecm/emetrp/v_47_y_1979_i_2_p_263-91.html)
On the other hand, they have asked: "Do you believe that stress is harmful to your health?" Again answering this question is very subjective depending on the same reference point.

Counter example: imagine subjects A has experienced so much disaster in their life that they have seen very negative health effects of stress. On the other hand, subject B has not experienced that much stress in their life. To both subjects, last year was highly stressful. Obviously, highly stressful for subject A means a complete disaster, and for subject B means a little worse than other years. When you ask them "Do you believe that stress is harmful to your health?", obviously, subject A responds yes because they have experienced very negative health effects, but subject B who has not experienced that much stress in their life would probably say no. Now, subject A will probably die earlier than subject B. Could you argue that dying earlier is because of believing stress is bad for you?

I believe this study is loosely measuring a correlation, and they cannot conclude a causal effect in this way. Please let me know if I am missing any point or I do not understand what they have done.